# jQuery images incorrectly displaying in div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Its been a while since I've been on here! I have a strange intermittent problem on a gallery page, that I strongly assume is related to some jQuery?!

http://www.savvysites.com/ASD/gallery.html#

Starting at this link, the first gallery images load up as expected! ?Sometimes? when going to the 2nd and/or 3rd gallery, the images load up halfway down the div as such:

http://prntscr.com/c7uyy

If anyone could shed some wisdom as to why this is happening (and offer a possible solution) I would be very grateful :)

...and if you're close to South Yarra, a beer is your reward!

regards
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pictures appear halfway down because of a margin-top of 0 (in combination with the absolute positioning and top:50%). In main.js there's a function called "imageResize(holder)" in which these values are set. I don't know for sure what's happening, but it seems img.height() sometimes return 0 when it shouldn't. Earlier in the function imageH is already set, so perhaps if you change the part where the margin-top is set to:

```
img.css({
  'margin-top':-(imgageH/2),
  'margin-left':-(imageW/2)
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help here Peer! I changed that CSS in main.js, and additionally in the HTML, i removed the "<span>clock</span>" tags, as these were then appearing over the top of some of the images...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what happens is, when you place the images on the page, it is putting it after the span tag.

The span tag holding the clock sometimes is in the middle of the box, therefore, putting the image half way down the box. with its absolute position.

Try to append the img tag relative to the `li` instead of the `span`.